# Can detached screens by "imported" inti active session?

Tags: gnu-screen, session, window-switching

I have a few screen sessions that I started from the native shell. Now, in order to switch from one to another, I always detach the current and re-attach the one I want to switch to which works fine but it would be great if my active screens could be "imported" to an attached session so that I can simply switch between screens with `^a n` & `^a p`. Is there an option to do this?

**EDIT1**
I realize that I can multiple sessions within one screen but what I'm wondering is, if I can import existing sessions?

Answer (score 0):

Run multiple screens in one screen, then you can switch with `<command char> N`. Choose other *command char* for the main screen with `screen -e ^eE`

Comment: Please see **EDIT1** above